# Why no memory leak error for static class member?

Tags: c++

I want to encapsulate a sorting class with some static functions, along with an auxiliary dynamic allocated array. And I was thinking where to `delete[]` the dynamic array lately. But I found that I got no memory leak error for it, neither for dynamic allocatd array in global scope. Why? What's rule here?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{
    static int *j;
};

int* Foo::j = new int[10]; //no memory leak error

// int *q = new int[10]; //no memory leak error
int main(){
    // int *q = new int[10]; //memory leak error
    return 0;
}
```

I use `clang++ -fsanitize=address -g -Wall main.cpp; ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out` to detect memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The allocated int[] is not lost in static/global case because it is reachable, why do you expect a memory leak ?

Comment: I try with this code and get memory leak error, https://ideone.com/G3GX1y

Comment: How does it being reachable change the fact that it leaks?

Comment: @TaQuangTu that isn't a leak. That's use-after-free undefined behaviour

Comment: That makes sense... Dynamic allocated memory not in local scope should not be worried about memory leak...

Comment: @TaQuangTu your code writes into a de allocated memory, this is invalid

Comment: @Quentin it's reachable for the entire lifetime of the program, and then collected by the OS

Comment: OK, I understand now, Thank all!

Comment: @Quentin an allocated memory is leak when there is no way to reach it directly or indirectly.

Comment: @bruno whether you could reach it or not is irrelevant if there's no code to release it anyway.

Comment: @quentin when an allocated memory stop to be reachable => you have no way to de allocate it => memory leak. Else there is no memory leak. The fact there is or not somewhere a piece of code de-allocated the memory is not relevant, only the execution counts.

Comment: @bruno how exactly could an execution path release the memory if there's no code to be executed in the first place? If we're talking memory resources only, your whole process' memory is freed by the OS upon exit regardless of whether it contains unreachable objects or not. If we're talking general resources, not destructing them properly is always a leak, reachable or not.

Comment: @quentin the rule is very simple. Supposing the memory leaks are search after the execution, so there is no thread so no stack, but the global variables/class attributes still exist, so the detector marks all the allocated memory blocks directly or indirectly reachable from the  global variables/class attributes, when this is done all the allocated memory blocks not marked are a memory leak.

Comment: @Quentin But since the OS would collect it, it's not a problem at all... I mean, don't we care memory leak only when the program is running? Btw, thank you for reminding me using `std::vector`. Thank you guys.

Comment: @bruno I'm sorry but that wouldn't make any sense. Marking reachable objects is just a QoL feature so that you know to search for either a missing `delete` or a lost pointer.

Comment: @Rick no we don't. Memory is a single resource type among many, and the OS won't help you with much else. Shared memory handles, database connections, specific driver state, etc. are all resources that won't be cleaned up if you just let them leak. Unless you desperately need to save a few milliseconds on program exit, there's no point in special-casing what your specific OS can or can't clean up.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, for those resource that OS won't help you clean up even if the program has terminated, release is indeed needed.

Answer (score 1):

Heap sanitizers frequently have trouble tracking allocations during the initialization of static objects, and this is what's happening here. There's no exception for global pointers, and your dynamically-allocated array leaks.

The only way to correctly release a global resource is the destructor of the object that manages it. In other words, use `std::vector` as usual.